# Pointwise convergence of an 'exotic' series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Enumerate the rational numbers as $q_1, q_2, \ldots$, and let $x$ be an irrational number.

Is the series $\sum_n \frac{1}{2^n} \tan(\frac{1}{x - q_n})$ convergent or divergent? On the one hand, $1/2^n$ diminishes 'rapidly', but on the other, since the rationals are dense, $\sup_n \tan(\frac{1}{x - q_n}) = 
\infty$, so the tan term sort of 'randomly' shrinks and grows unboundedly. I suppose that 'on average', the tan term is negative as frequently as it is positive, and so there's a chance it will converge, but surely this will depend on $x$.

Can anyone shed any light on this? I have a decent background in analysis, but no experience in areas like ergodic theory, which this sort of seems like to me. Thanks!

Comment: A small observation: Suppose that $(q_n)$ is arranged in such a way that the denominators of $q_n$ in lowest term grow sub-exponentially in $n$. Then for any irrational $x$ with finite irrationality measure, the sum converges absolutely.